# What is the black box around a post when using the comment keyboard shortcut (c)?

Tags: support, comments, design, keyboard-shortcuts

So when you use the comment shortcut <kbd>C</kbd>, you get the comment box appearing. However, you will get a weird black box.

Here's a picture of before:

> [image]

And afterwards:

> [image]

And after reloading, it disappears!
This seems weird.

And after looking at the HTML, this seems to be the problem:

```
<div data-questionid="260187" id="question" class="question keyboard-selected">
```

After removing the class attribute, the box goes away.

Comment: @Tim no, its not the whole HTML block. The `div` is the question. The part I'm pointing to is the `class` part

Answer (score 7):

This is not a bug. The box with those fading-in borders indicates that this post is selected (which will happen after you try to perform an operation which requires a specific post to be selected, i.e. voting or commenting) and any post-specific shortcuts you select apply to this post - unless you select next/prev post ( <kbd>j</kbd> / <kbd>k</kbd> ), then the "box" jumps to another post in this thread. That's useful when there're also answers to the question.

Comment: Then why is it not orange? The selected post color is orange

Comment: @Uni No, the orange is when you click the link which leads to some answer. In your case, this is the post which is selected with keyboard shortcuts. It was never orange, but indicated with this borders.

Comment: @Uni also, the class "keyboard-selected" seems to be self-explanatory - you selected the post with the keyboard, i.e. using shortcuts.

Comment: Hmm yeah the box also appears when using 'K' and 'J'

Comment: @Uni It moves from post to post, you see it?

Comment: Yes, I can see it. But it could be an outline

Comment: @Uni Not my fault that it's not outline, post a feature request to change its design. Anyway, the question you asked seems to be solved :)